# Show selected value in dropdown php from database

Tags: php, database

This is how I am trying to show the details when editing the form but gettin g error.

```
<select id="progcode" name="progcode">
    <option value="0">-none-</option>
    <option  value="1" <?php if($progcode == '1') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>PreS1-AB</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($progcode == '2') echo 'selected="selected"' ?> >PreS1-MM</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($progcode == '3') echo 'selected="selected"' ?> >TutEng</option>
</select>
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What error? Where is `$progcode` defined? What you want to do with `progcode` attribute on `option` when 2nd or 3rd option is selected?

Comment: I defined it at top at of the page.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: How? Put more relevant code please, this is just unrelevant code snippet which can is okay.

Comment: Sorry for this, I edited.

Comment: Can you defined/elaborate what error are you getting Mate

Comment: Showing undefined variable  Uchiha

Comment: Place more code, and paste the exact error @Tapash

Comment: But where its showing `undefined variable` need to place more code @Tapash

Comment: Ooo...I am sorry I recorrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is given blow---   And this is working fine,,,,,,
thank u all to suggest.

```
<select id="progcode" name="progcode">
                        <option value="0">-none-</option>
                        <option  value="1" <?php if($row["progcode"]==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>PreS1-AB</option>
                        <option value="2" <?php if($row["progcode"]==2) echo 'selected'; ?> >PreS1-MM</option>
                        <option value="3" <?php if($row["progcode"]==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>TutEng</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//here the simple way
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "ajaxcall";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $db);
if (!$con) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="name">
<option value=""> -----------ALL----------- </option> 
<?php
$query = "select DISTINCT id from crud";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='$rows[0]'> $rows[0] </option>";
}
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "ajaxcall";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $db);
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="name">
            <option value=""> -----------ALL----------- </option> 
            <?php
            $query = "select DISTINCT id from crud";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='$rows[0]'> $rows[0] </option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```